# JBoss AS 7 utilizando proxy com HTTPS

Tags: java, jboss, proxy

Tenho um servidor JBoss na minha máquina para testes em desenvolvimento. Na empresa onde trabalho temos um proxy. Estou precisando testar o recaptcha do Google. Ele usa https. Configurei as informações do proxy na tag  `system-properties` do arquivo `standalone.xml` do JBoss, conforme abaixo:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="http.proxyHost" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="http.proxyPort" value="8080"/>
    <property name="http.proxyUser" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="http.proxyPassword" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="http.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost"/>

    <property name="https.proxyHost" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="https.proxyPort" value="8080"/>
    <property name="https.proxyUser" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="https.proxyPassword" value="xxxx"/>
    <property name="https.nonProxyHosts" value="localhost"/>
</system-properties>
```

Porém ao executar alguma chamada que tenta usar o proxy, o servidor me retorna o seguinte erro:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

O que devo fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o certificado no arquivo de armazenamento de chaves utilizado na JVM e localizado em `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts`.

Primeiro você pode checar de seu certificado já está no arquivo de armazenamento de chaves executando o seguinte comando:

`keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`

Você não precisa especificar uma senha.

Se você não tem seu certificado você pode baixar isso utilizando seu navegador e adicionando isso para seu armazenamento de chaves com o seguinte comando:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file   <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```

Depois de importar você pode executar o primeiro comando para chegar novamente se o seu certificado foi adicionado.

Informações da Sun/Oracle podem ser encontradas aqui.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore